# QGIS "Fill Ring" tool error on SpatiaLite DB?

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I´m try Fill Ring tool on a SpatiaLite DB and I get a error on the Primary Key.
The Primary Key is integer auto increment.
When I insert the ring and try to save editing I receive error message duplicate key.

Ok, I can insert ring and add a new feature in, but I would like to make most quickly.

This is a problem or I am commiting any error?

Thanks!

version: QGIS Valmiera (Windows x86)

I've tested on Chugiak and I get that the inserted ring is not contained on the feature.